# How to remove the part of a shape that is not within the rectangle?

Tags: inkscape, flat-design

How can I keep just the part of the shape that is inside the rectangle?

I would like to do something like this:
[image]

Here's the original video I've seen this from: (StackExchange doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links, so I'll put the link in a comment to this question).

What is the technique used by the designer to keep just the part of the circles that are within the rectangles? I tried slowing the video down to 0.25, and all I've seen is that he went to the **Path** section, but I don't know what he clicked on.

Here's my "remake"
[image]

As you can see from my "remake", the circle is above the rectangle, but I can't hide the part that is not within the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

After trying various methods, I finally found a solution.

All I had to do was just duplicate both the rectangle and the circle. While keeping the duplicates selected, i clicked on **Intersection** in the **Path** menu, and all that remained was just the part of the circle that was inside the rectangle.

Here's my "remake" (not finished yet but you can see the circles)
[image]

Comment: You should probably use clipping masks in this case though.