# Remove part of shape that's outside another shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am trying to cut a part of a shape that is outside another one using illustrator.

I've found [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/94992/how-to-remove-the-part-of-a-shape-that-is-not-within-the-rectangle) answer for Inkscape and I tried to reproduce it with Illustrator but I did not success.

[image]

I'd like to remove the part of the green shape that is outside the other one. When I try to use **Pathfinder** -> **subtract**  it creates a hole in it.

I found if I use **Pathfinder** -> **substract (front - back)** Illustrator is keeping only the part I want to delete. I could copy paste that part onto my original shape and paint it the same color as the background but I don't like this solution...

P.S. What is the name of the operation I'm trying to do ? I have little to no knowledge about Illustrator and Graphic Design in general so I have trouble googling stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use **Pathfinder > Divide** to do exactly what you're asking to do. 
The divide action will also group the objects, so they need to be ungrouped or you need to double click into the group - and then manually select and delete the portions that need to go.

Comment: Oooooh, I did not know I had to go in and manually delete stuff, I  tried every option in **Pathfinder** and I though **Divide** was not doing anything in my case...
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I also needed to do **Object** -> **Expand** when my shape was a bit weird